# PHP zip deleteName deletes too much

Tags: php, file, zip, delete-file

here is the content of my original zip:

- admin/
- images/
- include/
- index.php
- install.php
- styles/
- template/
- upload/
- web/

If i run this code:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
    if ($zip->open('update.zip') === TRUE) {

        $zip->deleteName('include/mysql.php');
        $zip->deleteName('install.php');

        $zip->extractTo('./update/');

        $zip->close();

        unlink('./update.zip');

    } else {
        echo 'Fehler';
    }
```

the files that are left are:

- admin/
- images/
- include/

all others are deleted. Any idea why?

Comment: What happens if you don't delete anything? What does $zip extract then?

Comment: Then it does extracts evrything properly. Only if it try with that deleteName it deletes too much...

Comment: What happens if you delete other files instead of those ones? Does the output change? Any differences between the different directories? Do all of them have files?

Comment: All contain files. 
deleteName() deletes all files and dirs under itself and itself (see first post)
e.g. if i delete admin/ everything is deleted...

Comment: Loop through all the file names using this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ziparchive-statname.php and echo out the index for each one. Might be easier to delete the files using index and not name.

Comment: no need too loop: 
    $i =  $zip->locateName('install.php');
    $zip->deleteIndex($i);
but it is also not working same problem

Comment: Have you checked whether if shows different indexes for each file and directory?

Comment: I have replicated this and it works perfectly for me. Try a different zip file perhaps.

Comment: Could you try this one http://www.motion-coding.com/upload/m-cms.zip

Comment: Same symptoms as you reported. There is something wrong with the file I guess.

Comment: also same error with other zips - maybe because zipped by default mac archiver? -> adds some hidden index files

Comment: It would definitely point out to that. I suggest you might want to file a bug at https://bugs.php.net/

Comment: Archives from other archivers also fail mhhh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to close the ZIP file after deleteName(), then open again to extract.

```
<?php
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open('update.zip') === TRUE) {

    $zip->deleteName('include/mysql.php');
    $zip->deleteName('install.php');
    $zip->close();

    $zip->open('update.zip');
    $zip->extractTo('./update/');
    $zip->close();

    unlink('./update.zip');

} else {
    echo 'Fehler';
}
?>
```

Comment: it's a pleasure.i guess that: before closing the zip file, deleteName() have changed structure of zip-file but saved. so exactact it unexpected.(Sorry for my poor English...)